# Sticky variable value in lua vim.keymap

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to create a mapping in my neovim lua setup such that when I have a visual selection and hit `<leader>ps`, a telescope search is initiated with the selected text.
Here is what I have for the moment:

```lua
local builtin = require('telescope.builtin')

local function get_visual_selection()
  local s_start = vim.fn.getpos("'<")
  local s_end = vim.fn.getpos("'>")
  local n_lines = math.abs(s_end[2] - s_start[2]) + 1
  local lines = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_lines(0, s_start[2] - 1, s_end[2], false)
  lines[1] = string.sub(lines[1], s_start[3], -1)
  if n_lines == 1 then
    lines[n_lines] = string.sub(lines[n_lines], 1, s_end[3] - s_start[3] + 1)
  else
    lines[n_lines] = string.sub(lines[n_lines], 1, s_end[3])
  end
  return table.concat(lines, '\n')
end

vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>ps', function() -- works fine
    builtin.grep_string({ search = vim.fn.input("Grep > ") });
end)

vim.keymap.set('v', '<leader>ps', function() -- gets the same first value for sel everytime!
    local sel = get_visual_selection();
    builtin.grep_string({ search = vim.fn.input("Grep > " .. sel) });
end)
```

This code works on the first time; but then the first text retrieved from selection never changes! I get the first text I selected over and over. I don't understand what is causing that. It seems the function gets hit by some sort of caching mechanism from lua...?

Answer (score 0):

I finally used a different and simpler way of doing this exact thing using a remap, yank and paste; I still don't know what's wrong in my question's lua script though.

Here is the working lua map:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('v', '<leader>ps', 'y<leader>ps<C-r>*', { remap = true });
```